# session is not initialize when declared php

Tags: php, session, mysqli, session-variables, session-state

my code

```
$password = md5($password);
$sql2="SELECT uid from users WHERE uemail='$emailusername' or uname='$emailusername' and upass='$password'";

//checking if the username is available in the table
 $result = mysqli_query($this->db,$sql2);
$user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$count_row = $result->num_rows;
if ($count_row == 1) {
    $_SESSION['login'] = true; 
    // this login var will use for the session thing 
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $user_data['uid'];
    $_SESSION['fullname'] = $user_data['fullname'];
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

as you can see from above code, it first check if theres match uemail or uname where password is equal $password and then if there's a record found then session true, create session uid and session fullname but it seems that session fullname is not been initialize as i tried also to echo session fullname (assume that i successfully match the records) and it give me an error like it hasn't been declared. What suppose to be the problem in my code? any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

PS: assume that i have stored the $_POST['emailusername'] into $emailusername variable and assume that I have started the session declaration by adding session_start() on the head.

Comment: where is `$emailusername` defined^

Comment: Where in your code is `session_start()`?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: assume that i have stored the post_['emailusername'[ into $emailusername variable and assume that I have started the session declaration by adding session_start on the head.

Comment: @Styphon: assume that i have stored the post_['emailusername'[ into $emailusername variable and assume that I have started the session declaration by adding session_start on the head.

Comment: Then you should show it because it's an important information.

Comment: @Pierre-JeanBergeron: updated post. I apologize for the lack of info.

Comment: @CodeDemon You'd be amazed out how many people actually forget that information, so you need to include it in your original question so we that's not the problem :)

Comment: @Styphon: yeah my bad. I must be more precise and more detailed next time.

Comment: Right after `session_start();` add `$_SESSION['test'] = 'test'; var_dump($_SESSION);` and check to make sure that works. If it doesn't then post all your code around where `session_start()` is.

Comment: thank you for the answer. but seems I catered my needs by trying different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line at the top of **every page** to initialize sessions:

```
session_start();
```

PHP doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: assume that i have stored the post_['emailusername'[ into $emailusername variable and assume that I have started the session declaration by adding session_start() on the head.